# ASP.NET MVC3 Deleting a record using a sub-form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to delete a record being displayed in a table on my ManageUser view using a sub-form, thus

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" summary="User Grid" style="text-align: left">
    <tr style="background-color: #ABC3CB;">
        <th align="center">User Name</th>
        <th align="center">Approved</th>
        <th align="center">&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="center">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach(MembershipUser membershipUser in ViewData.Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%: membershipUser.UserName %></td>
            <td align="center"><%: Html.CheckBox(" ", true, membershipUser.IsApproved )  %></td>
            <td align="center">
                <% using (Html.BeginForm( "DeleteItem", "Admin", new { id = membershipUser.UserName } )) { %>
                    <input type="image" src="<%: Url.Content( "~/Content/Images/Delete.jpg" ) %>" />
                <% } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

The ManageUser view is displayed by the following code in the AdminController, thus

```
    public ViewResult ManageUser( string searchType, string searchInput )
{
    List<SelectListItem> searchOptionList = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Value="UserName", Text = "UserName"},
        new SelectListItem() {Value="Email", Text = "Email"},
    };

    ViewData["searchOptionList"] = new SelectList( searchOptionList, "Value", "Text", searchType ?? "UserName" );
    ViewData["searchInput"] = searchInput ?? string.Empty;
    ViewData["searchType"] = searchType;

    MembershipUserCollection viewData;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty( searchInput ))
        viewData = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    else if (searchType == "Email")
        viewData = Membership.FindUsersByEmail( searchInput );
    else
        viewData = Membership.FindUsersByName( searchInput );

    ViewData["PageTitle"] = "Account Management";
    return View( viewData );
    }
```

When I display the page, and select the Delete choice, I expect it to run Admin/DeleteItem in the AdminController, thus

```
    public RedirectToRouteResult DeleteItem( string id )
{
    Membership.DeleteUser( id );
    return RedirectToAction( "ManageUser" );
}
```

but instead, it is returning directly to the Admin/ManagerUser view, thus displaying my original set of records again.

I have obviously missed something but I cannot see what. Anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML `<form>` elements cannot be nested. Nesting them results in unexpected behavior which could vary between different browsers. Quote from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html):

> Every form must be enclosed within a
>   FORM element. There can be several
>   forms in a single document, but the
>   FORM element can't be nested.

So you might need to remove the outer form or find another way of organizing your markup.

Comment: But this is a technique shown in Steven Sanderson's book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework" and it works in his SportsStore demo under MVC 2. Has there been a change in MVC 3?

Comment: @xiecs, I very highly doubt that there are nested forms shown in the "Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework" book and if there are it's definitely not good. This is something that has been around since the existence of the HTML specification and has absolutely nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. You just can't nest HTML forms.

Comment: @xiecs, are you referring to the `~/Views/Admin/Index.aspx` view in the `Sports Store` demo? There are no nested forms. You have multiple forms generated for each element allowing to delete each product but they are never nested inside an outer form which is what you seem to be doing.

Comment: It appears I have one too many "<th align="center">&nbsp;</th>" in my example.

Comment: I don't see how the forms are nested. They are individual forms in each row of a table, just like pages 162/163 of Sanderson's book.

Comment: @xiecs, I see that you have an `Html.CheckBox` outside of your form which makes me to believe that your entire table is inside another `<form>`. Unfortunately you haven't shown your entire view so it is difficult to say for sure.

Comment: You are right. I do have a BeginForm around the entire form. If I remove it, the delete works fine. Thank you for your help. But what are the implications of removing it?

Comment: @xiecs, I don't know what the implications would be for your application. You put this form with some purpose. So it's up to you to say what the implications would be. The only implication I can tell you is that removing it you will have valid HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for my application, but the implications in general. You state above that every form should have a FORM element. To avoid nested forms, I will have to remove an enclosing Body <%: BeginForm ... from every view, particularly my Site.Master. If I do that, some views will have no FORM element at all.

Comment: @xiecs, and what bothers you if there are views that have no forms at all? That's MVC, not classic WebForms where you were forced to have a single form element on each page.